# Angular Fetch exact local ip address

Tags: angular, fetch, ip, ip-address, angular14

I need to fetch local ip address of my machine even it is masked or connected with other networks. Is there any way to show the actual ip without doing any 3rd party local host or anything?

I tried some of the ways that mentioned on the sites but it is not showing the exact result I needed. It only displays the ip of public network. If it is not possible by typescript is there any way to do it on javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply solved using javascrip, solution down below.

```
let currentUrl = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.hostname + ":" + document.location.port;
console.log(currentUrl);
```

The above code will give you the current url of the build.

Comment: I think it shows only the local host, I need to show the ip address .Any idea?

Comment: If it is running on local, you will get local host or else you will get the ip address. This is working for me, please have a look.